# Count if matching items in same column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

**The Set Up:**

I have a single column, with three cells.
These cells are drop-down lists. (177 options in the drop-down).

**Trying to figure out:**
I want to automate matching (if two or all three items match in the same column, to each other) and return a specific number.

[Column that needs to match.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvJA0.png) [Output in other column.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xs6HC.png)

So a normal "countif" isn't going to work, as I would need to specify what is being counted. I need it to "see" that there is a match and spit out a specific number.

[Sample in works](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DPpcOB1J0DLe2mCW-MQy6p9dlX2FW45xE0T23Iq0KvA/edit?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0):

- if `A1 = A2 = A3` = 30 points
- if `A1 = A2` = 20 points
- if `A1 = A3` = 20 points
- if `A2 = A3` = 20 points
- if non are same = 10 points

---

```
=IF(AND(A1=A2, A2=A3), 30,
 IF(OR(A1=A2, A1=A3, A2=A3), 20, 10))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Cries out for [COUNTUNIQUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093405). Assuming relevant dropdowns are in B10:B12 :

```
=countunique(B10:B12)
```

and if `1`, `2`, and `3` are not suitable for the `"specific number"` then these can be mapped to suitable alternatives (I chose `7` for all the same, `0` if all different, and `3` otherwise):

```
=choose(countunique(B10:B12),7,3,0)
```